# how to get the public ip address of the user of openerp?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, openerp-7

I want to control the sign_in for openerp by the public ip address of the user, for that I tried to compare the IP user by an existant IP

The code below is showing the public IP:

```
my_ip = urlopen('http://ip.42.pl/raw').read()
```

i've modified the code of _altern_si_so function in hr_attendance, by adding some lines

```
def _altern_si_so(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

        if my_ip=='aa.aa.aa.aa': # Want to compare IP user by 'aa.aa.aa.aa'
            return False
    return True

msg = 'Error ! Sign in (resp. Sign out) must follow Sign out (resp. Sign in)'
my_ip = urlopen('http://ip.42.pl/raw').read()# get public ip address

_constraints = [(_altern_si_so, my_ip, ['action'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from openerp.http import request

public_ip = request.httprequest.remote_addr
```

The request object contains the remote address. You should be able to access this and use it for your needs.